# How to create IPA without Developer Account credentials in Xcode6

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

One of my customers won't provide access to his Developer Portal & iTunes Connect credentials. With Xcode 5 we have used this flow to submit apps for review:

- Customer sends me Distribution Certificate & App Store Provisioning Profile
- I generate an IPA with these credentials and export it for Ad-Hoc distribution
- I send the IPA to customer
- Customer submits it to iTunes Connect using App Loader

Now as I can see that Xcode 6 doesn't allow me to build IPA even for Ad-Hoc development without a developer login and password. Is there any way to generate an IPA without credentials?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@frozen_lion you can still use xcodebuild to export ipa without Developer Account access:

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath $projectname.xcarchive -exportPath $projectname -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile “Provisioning Profile Name”
```

More details you can find in this article [Using xcodebuild To Export a .ipa From an Archive](http://www.thecave.com/2014/09/16/using-xcodebuild-to-export-a-ipa-from-an-archive/)

Answer (score 6):

You should use Xcode6.1.1, it was supported. Choose "Use local signing assets" by accounts dropdown box.